# cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/i915_display_info: Operation not permitted

Tags: 16.04, kernel

I want to get display info of my current system.So I used the following command:

```
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/i915_display_info
```

It displays me : `cat: /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/i915_display_info: Operation not permitted`

The above command works in various ubuntu systems (16.04-64 bit).But it is in my system having the same ubuntu 16.04-64 bit;it gives error.

**My System Info:**

```
Kernel version:4.15.0-42-generic    
Distributor ID: Ubuntu    
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS    
Release:    16.04    
Codename:   xenial
```

**Edit:The output of sudo -l**

```
Matching Defaults entries for test on test-NUC7i5DNKE:
    env_reset, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User test may run the following commands on test-NUC7i5DNKE:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

**Things I have tried:**

1. **sudo -s** and gave the command **without sudo**,it gives me the same error.

I have tried searching to solve this issue in various forums but couldn't find one.Any inputs will be really helpful!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please run `sudo -l` and add to your question!

Answer (score 0):

Use these steps:

1. `sudo -i`, then run
2. `cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/i915_display_info`

Switch to root with `sudo -i` then run that `cat` command and you should get the info your looking for!

Comment: Thanks for the reply...it gives me the same error